# sweetAlert2 keeps returning true and overriding my main action

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

I'm trying to override the default confirm() dialog with the sweetAlert2 confirm dialog.

However it continues to return and continue with the deletion process without clicking OK.

```
    $("a.confirm").click(function(){
        swal({   
              title: 'Are you sure?',   
              text: $(this).attr('data-message'),   
              type: 'warning',   
              showCancelButton: true,   
              confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',   
              cancelButtonColor: '#d33',   
              confirmButtonText: 'Yes',   
              closeOnConfirm: true }, 
              function(isConfirm) { 
                if(isConfirm === true){
                    alert('it is true');
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
             });
    });
```

The idea for this is simple. I have a class on any link that may require a confirmation, the message for the confirmation is assigned to a data-message attribute.

More often than not, it automatically skips to the URL instead of waiting for the OK button to be clicked.

I have looked at the examples which display an additional dialog saying thank you to the user, but in this case I'm trying to simply return true only when clicking OK. not to display an additional dialog.

Any tips greatly appreciated

Comment: This plugin isn't modal, it doesn't wait for response. I'm not sure what are you expecting with `return false;`? If you want to prevent default behaviour of link click, then anyway you have to set it in handler, not wrapped plugin anonymous function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your expected behaviour:

```
$("a.confirm").click(function (e) {
    var _self = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: $(this).attr('data-message'),
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        closeOnConfirm: true
    }, function (isConfirm) {    
        if (isConfirm === true) {
            _self.click();
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution was very close, I ended up catching the href attribute and making the window.location the link if it returned true